# Flutter Bloc: Why is a child BlocBuilder built with new state before parent BlocListener is notified?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have a root-level `BlocListener` that listens to my global `AuthBloc` for auth state changes and uses `Navigator` to return to the login page if a user signs out.

A descendant `HomePage` widget also consumes that auth state under the assumption that `AuthBloc` is in an `AuthenticatedState` if it's being built. However, upon signing out, the child `HomePage` is built with the new `UnauthenticatedState` before the root `BlocListener` has had a chance to navigate back to login.

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // assume AuthBloc has already been provided
    return BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is! AuthenticatedState) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
          // ^--- I expect this to be called before HomePage gets UnauthenticatedState
        }
      },
      child: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        // state == Unauthenticated after signing out  <------
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Is this expected behavior or should there be a guaranteed `parent->child` order of updates? What are the recommended patterns for dealing with this?

Comment: I just ran into this issue myself. I'll be making a new widget that uses a `BlocSelector` to ensure that the required state is present, and build a `SizedBox.shrink` if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Add **condition** inside BlocBuilder of HomePage like this:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 @override

 Widget build(BuildContext) {
  return BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
    condition: (AuthState previousState, AuthState currentState) => currentState is AuthenticatedState,
    builder: (context, state) {
     /// Build your home page screen here
    }
  );
}
```

}

Comment: I think it's `buildWhen` now, not `condition`. But I don't think that solves my problem because that simply determines when the widget should be rebuilt. I can conditionally render an empty container in `HomeScreen` if the state isn't what I need, but that leads to a brief empty screen as the new state eventually reaches the navigator.